# Carrierwave: Passing User_ID in Nested Form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, carrierwave

Having problems saving the user_id to the database table Documents. Right now, it's not sending anything associated with user_id for documents when I check the rails server log in POST.

**projects_controller.rb**

```
def new_step_3
  project = Project.new
  @project.documents.build
end
```

**new_step_3.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for @project, :html => {:multipart => true} do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :title %>
  <%= f.text_field :description %>

  <%= f.fields_for :documents do |builder| %>
    <%= builder.file_field :title %>
  <% end %>

  <%= f.text_field :skills %>
  <%= f.submit 'Post Project' %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did u include line `accepts_nested_attributes_for :documents` in your project model?

Comment: Yes. and setup the associations as well.